# How to assign values from a data list having three fields to an empty list index wise? (java)

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have two lists: `list1` and `list2`. Both lists are of type **Information class** which has **3 fields.**

`list1` has 99 values, `list2` is empty. I want to add 9 values to `list2` from `list1`.

The issue I'm getting is every time I try to add to `list2` as

```
for(int i=0;i<=8;i++)
{
   list2.add(list1.get(i)); 
   //or
   list2.add(i,list1.get(i));
}
```

It throws an out of memory exception on run time, or I get unsupported operation exception. Any help would be great.

Comment: Post the stacktrace you get

Comment: Please post the full code.  Nothing I see actually looks wrong to me.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you've posted.

Comment: Sorry for that I cannot provide it by now. I deleted all my code because it was't working. Yet, can you tell such technique that I can assign values and no exception comes. Is there any optimal way to do so?

Comment: The code you've posted shouldn't cause the sort of exception you specified. It must be a problem somewhere else in your code.

Comment: The loop I'm running is in a constructor ...

Comment: Maybe you are continuosly creating new instances of your class causing the memory to get filled up very quickly

Comment: Yep, I think you have some class `MyList` and inside its constructor you're making `new MyList()` so it's infinite recursion and never ends => `StackOverflowError`

Comment: It gives out of memory error, is this same as StackOverFllowError ?